Error Using react-native-static-server for Loading Local HTML in WebView (Objective C BOOL Conversion Issue)
I am developing a React Native app with a WebView to load an HTML package from the local file system. I am focusing on iOS development first and will work on Android later.
Below is the code I’m using to load the HTML file:
App.js
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const pathURI =
    Platform.OS === 'android'
      ? 'file:///android_asset/samples/index.html'
      : `${RNFS.MainBundlePath}/samples/index.html`;

<WebView
  source={{uri: pathURI}}
  style={styles.webview}
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  allowFileAccess={true}
  allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
  onError={syntheticEvent => {
    const {nativeEvent} = syntheticEvent;
    console.log('WebView error:', nativeEvent);
  }}
  onHttpError={syntheticEvent => {
    const {nativeEvent} = syntheticEvent;
    console.log('HTTP error:', nativeEvent);
  }}
  onMessage={event => {
    console.log('WebView log:', event.nativeEvent.data);
  }}
/>

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="loaderwrap">LOADING...</div>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

index.js
window.addEventListener('load', evt => {
  console.log('Window Loaded');
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log('onreadystatechange', xhttp.status, xhttp.readyState);
    if (xhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhttp.status === 200) {
        console.log('Response:', xhttp.responseText);
      } else {
        console.log('Error:', xhttp.statusText);
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open('GET', 'data.json', true);
  xhttp.send();
  console.log('Window onload code executed');
});

Issue:
The index.html and index.js files load successfully, and the window.onload function executes. However, the XMLHttpRequest does not execute because it requires a web server to function.
To solve this, I used the react-native-static-server package with the following code:
import StaticServer from 'react-native-static-server';

const pathURI =
    Platform.OS === 'android'
      ? 'file:///android_asset/samples'
      : `${RNFS.MainBundlePath}/samples`;

useEffect(() => {
  const server = new StaticServer(8080, pathURI, {
    localOnly: true,
  });

  server.start().then(url => {
    console.log(`Server started at ${url}`);
  });
}, []);

Error:
When I run the above code, I get the following error:
Error: FPStaticServer.start(): Error while converting JavaScript argument 2 to Objective C type BOOL. Objective C type BOOL is unsupported.
I’ve ensured that localOnly: true is included, but I’m not sure where I’m going wrong.
I’ve attached the package.json file in case it helps to understand the installed libraries and their versions.
package.json
{
  "name": "OliveQSolDemo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.76.5",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-static-server": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.12.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.76.3",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.76.3",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.76.3",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.76.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^4.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}

Can someone help me identify the issue or provide guidance on how to resolve this error?
